# How to get embedding from bert finetuned model?

Tags: pytorch, transformer-model, bert-language-model

I have finedtuned 'bert-base-uncased' model using transformer and torch which gave me pytorch_model.bin, vocab.txt and other files as output.
After loading the model how to I get embedding for complete vocab, like a matrix which maps every word to its embedding vector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to use [Huggingface](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers), they make it very easy to use and train all Transformer model variants.

To get the embedding from a BERT fine-tuned model, you could use [BertModel.set_input_embeddings()](https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/bert.html#transformers.BertModel.get_input_embeddings).